# Magento 2.4 Hide Price from Recently viewed products for certain products

Tags: price, hide

I want to **hide Price from recently viewed products** for certain products only(Based on its attribute value).How can I do that? Please anyone help me to do that.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have added answer. Please check and approve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by below piece of code. Here i have load product using product repository in phtml file , but you can load it anywhere (In helper, block file)

Here i have attribute code name "new" so i am applying condition for show/hide price on the basis of "new"(boolean) attribute value.

First , please override **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml** file in your theme (**app/design/frontend/packangename/theme/Magento_Catalog/view/templates/product/list/items.phtml**).

Copy and paste all code from core file in theme overridden file. Find function getProductPrice($_item) in file and set below code according to your attribute value

```
<?php 
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $product = $productRepository->getById($_item->getId());
?>
<?php if($product->getNew()): ?>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This way you can show/hide price for certain products only(Based on its attribute value).

Please check and let me know if you have any query.